# How to grab URL from Wikipedia by API?

Tags: php, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I have list of company names. What I want to do is, to get their websites by company names. Let's say we want to grab "Website" from [Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft) Wikipedia page.

[image]

The query below doesn't return this information

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&format=json&titles=microsoft

Any suggestions to get only website field?

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to do that with [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&titles=Microsoft) because the homepage url format can be different and the link can be nested in many templates, and probably will have to use regex. Better variant is to use [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities).

So, the article [Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft) in Wikipedia is associated with Wikidata item [Microsoft (Q2283)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2283), which has property [official website (P856)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P856), which means that you need to get this property from the response of this request:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&sites=enwiki&languages=en&props=claims&titles=Microsoft
```

The last will returns directly the url of the official website:

```
{
    ....
    "P856":[{
        "mainsnak":{
            "datavalue":{
                "value":"https://www.microsoft.com"
            },
        },
    }]
    ....
}
```

If you need a list of all Wikidata items which have property P856 and [P1128 (employees)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1128) and also include a link to English Wikipedia, you can use [WikidataQuery API](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html):

```
http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[1128] AND claim[856] AND link[enwiki]
```